# Как сделать выделение объекта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу сделать выделение объекта, чтобы этот объект остановился больше при нажатии на него, а когда выбирал другой, другой становился больше, а предыдущий меньше. Я хочу сделать магазин в игре и для выбора скина хочу выделять его.

Есть 20 картинок с BoxCollider2D, которые я могу двигать по оси X. Пробовал через Raycast, но я не силен в этом, поэтому особо не получилось. К тому же сомневался - смогу ли я сделать возможность покупок через PlayerPrefs. Еще не понимаю, как это будет работать на Android и будет ли вообще.

[image: Shop]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]